# How to check if number is correct after insert trigger oracle sql

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I am a beginner at sql and Ive been stuck on this problem for weeks now, I just cant figure it out.
So i signed up here to hopefully get some help.

Simplified explanation:
I have 2 tables, account and deposition that looks like this

```
create table ACCOUNT(
    acc_id number(8),
    accty_id number(6) not null,    
    date_time date not null,
    balance number(10,2) not null);
alter table ACCOUNT
    add constraint account_acc_id_pk primary key(acc_id)
    add constraint account_accty_id_fk foreign key(accty_id) references ACCOUNT_TYPE(accty_id);
```

```
create table DEPOSITION(
    dep_id number(9),
    cust_id varchar2(11) not null,      
    acc_id number(8) not null,
    amount number(10,2) not null,
    date_time date not null);
alter table DEPOSITION
    add constraint deposition_dep_id_pk primary key(dep_id)
    add constraint deposition_cust_id_fk foreign key(cust_id) references CUSTOMER(cust_id)
    add constraint deposition_acc_id_fk foreign key(acc_id) references ACCOUNT(acc_id);
```

I also have a function called get_balance that looks like this:

```
create or replace function get_balance(
    p_acc_id in account.acc_id%type)
    return number
as
    v_balance account.balance%type;
    errormes varchar2(1000);
    errorcode number(10);
begin
    select balance
    into v_balance
    from account
    where p_acc_id = acc_id;
        return v_balance;
exception
    when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('Account not found, check account number');
        return null;
    when others then
    errormes := sqlerrm;
    errorcode := sqlcode;
    dbms_output.put_line('something went wrong');
    dbms_output.put_line('error code: ' ||sqlcode);
    dbms_output.put_line('error message: '||sqlerrm);
end;
```

the problem is that I want to design an after insert trigger on the deposition table which make sure that the amount deposited to an account is correct and prints out that the balance is correct or incorrect after deposition.

As far as I know, I cant access the old value of balance on the account before deposition with after insert, then how can I check that the balance is correct after deposition?
If I call the get_balance function, i think that i will just get the balance after the deposition has occured, which returns new balance?

The balance on the account is updated with the following procedure:

```
create or replace procedure do_deposition(  
    p_cust_id in deposition.cust_id%type,
    p_acc_id in deposition.acc_id%type,
    p_amount in deposition.amount%type)
as
    v_balance account.balance%type;
    errormes varchar2(1000);
    errorcode number(10);
begin   
    insert into deposition(dep_id, cust_id, acc_id, amount, date_time)
    values(pk_seq.nextval, p_cust_id, p_acc_id, p_amount, sysdate);
    commit;
    update account 
    set balance = balance + p_amount
    where acc_id = p_acc_id;
    commit;
    dbms_output.put_line('Balance in account' || p_acc_id ||' after deposition :'||get_balance(p_acc_id));
exception 
    when others then
    errormes := sqlerrm;
    errorcode := sqlcode;
    dbms_output.put_line('something went wrong in do_deposition');
    dbms_output.put_line('error code: ' ||sqlcode);
    dbms_output.put_line('error message: '||sqlerrm);
end;
```

I know that there is probably a lot wrong with this but I cant seem to find any examples that resembles this problem.
Please forgive my ignorance, any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is my first post so im sorry if I have done something wrong in my post

Thanks

- a humble sql beginner

Some of my many attempts:

```
create or replace trigger aifer_deposition  
after insert
on deposition
for each row
declare 
    v_acc_id account.acc_id%type;
    v_balance account.balance%type;
begin
    select acc_id, balance
    into v_acc_id, v_balance
    from account 
    where v_acc_id = :new.acc_id;
    if (v_balance = (v_balance + :new.amount)) then
        dbms_output.put_line('Correct amount deposited');
    else        
        dbms_output.put_line('Incorrect amount deposited ');
    end if;
end;
```

```
create or replace trigger aifer_deposition  
after insert
on deposition
for each row
begin
    if account.acc_id = :new.acc_id then
    account.balance = account.balance + :new.amount;
    dbms_output.put_line('Correct amount deposited');
    else        
        dbms_output.put_line('Incorrect amount deposited ');
    end if;
end;
```

But its clear that I am missing some basic knowledge regarding after insert triggers since these do not work

Comment: How are these not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are keeping the delta `amount` and the running `balance` in two different tables. The insert of one table and the update of another are two separate actions and would require two triggers that would not be able to communicate.

1. The first option is to not try to put this verification synchronously with your inserts/updates. *Create a schedule job* that on occasion (daily, etc..) adds up all your delta amounts and compares it to the balance and reports any inconsistencies.
2. The second option is a small redesign: *place the running balance in the same table as the delta amount*. Now you can do a trigger that can compare the previous row with the new row and perform your verification checks. But what if this or any other trigger you come up with is disabled by a DBA for some reason? You can't rely on triggers for data consistency. You'll end up needing a scheduled job to check it asynchronously anyway. And, this doesn't get away from the violation of 3rd normal form by storing a derivative value.
3. The last option is to *not record the balance at all*, at least not in your primary source tables. In data modeling we want to have one source of truth so there isn't a possibility of two related pieces of data being in disagreement. You can simply calculate it at query time by adding up the deltas. Or for performance, you can have a summary table that is *known* to be derivative in nature and therefore not a source of truth, which you can populate with a scheduled job. You can also populate it with a trigger to get it real-time, and then have a schedule job correct it on occasion in case your trigger was disabled for any reason. But you'll always treat it as derivative/aggregate data.

In summary, there is no way to guarantee that `amount` and `balance`, whether in one table or two, are in sync with each other at all times in all circumstances. A trigger can get disabled. Someone can do DML outside of your procedure (even if nobody has permissions, they can get permissions). You can introduce a bug into your procedure unintentionally, etc.. this is the problem with derived attributes. Therefore, either calculate the derived value at query time only, or build in scheduled correction mechanisms to keep things in sync and allow for the possibility of inconsistency in the interval of time between those corrections.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use triggers for error checking. If you want to perform some checks then do it in the procedure you are using to add the deposits.
- Don't `COMMIT` multiple times in the procedure. If you successfully insert into the `deposition` table and then the `update` of the `account` table fails and you have `COMMIT`ted between the statements then it will be impossible to `ROLLBACK` the first change.
- In general, it is bad practice to `COMMIT` in a procedure. If you want to chain multiple procedure calls together within a transaction then you want to be able to run them all and if there is an error in the last procedure called then roll them all back. If you `COMMIT` in the procedures then this becomes impossible; instead `COMMIT` from the code where you call procedures (after the procedures have run).
- In general, it is bad practice to catch the `OTHERS` exception. If there are going to be known exceptions (such as `NO_DATA_FOUND` or `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX`) then handle those explicitly. If there are unknown exceptions then don't catch them; let them be raised, any changes will `ROLLBACK` and then a developer can debug the procedure so that they can fix the issue. If you catch the exception (even if you output it to the console) then you are effectively hiding the errors as the code will appear to run successfully.

For example:

```sql
create table ACCOUNT(
    acc_id    number(8)
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
              not null,
    accty_id  number(6)    not null,    
    date_time date         not null,
    balance   number(10,2) not null
);

alter table ACCOUNT
    add constraint account_acc_id_pk primary key(acc_id)
    -- add constraint account_accty_id_fk foreign key(accty_id) references ACCOUNT_TYPE(accty_id)
;

create table DEPOSITION(
    dep_id    number(9)
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
              not null,
    cust_id   varchar2(11) not null,      
    acc_id    number(8)    not null,
    amount    number(10,2) not null,
    date_time date         not null
);

alter table DEPOSITION
    add constraint deposition_dep_id_pk primary key(dep_id)
    -- add constraint deposition_cust_id_fk foreign key(cust_id) references CUSTOMER(cust_id)
    add constraint deposition_acc_id_fk foreign key(acc_id) references ACCOUNT(acc_id);
```

Then you can have the procedure:

```sql
create or replace procedure do_deposition(  
  p_cust_id in deposition.cust_id%type,
  p_acc_id in deposition.acc_id%type,
  p_amount in deposition.amount%type
)
as
  v_balance     account.balance%type;
  v_balance_chk account.balance%type;
begin   
  UPDATE account 
  SET   balance = balance + p_amount
  WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id
  RETURNING balance INTO v_balance;

  INSERT INTO deposition(cust_id, acc_id, amount, date_time)
  VALUES (p_cust_id, p_acc_id, p_amount, sysdate);

  SELECT SUM(amount)
  INTO   v_balance_chk
  FROM   deposition
  WHERE  acc_id = p_acc_id;

  IF v_balance != v_balance_chk THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
      -20000,
      'Balance does not match depositions: ' || v_balance || ' : ' || v_balance_chk
    );
  END IF;

  dbms_output.put_line('Balance in account ' || p_acc_id ||' after deposition: '|| v_balance);

end;
/
```

Then, if you have the data:

```sql
INSERT INTO account (accty_id, date_time, balance)
VALUES (1, SYSDATE, 0);

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  do_deposition(1, 1, +100);
  do_deposition(1, 1,  -20);
  do_deposition(1, 1,  +50);
  do_deposition(1, 1, -300);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Balance in account 1 after deposition: 100
> Balance in account 1 after deposition: 80
> Balance in account 1 after deposition: 130
> Balance in account 1 after deposition: -170
> ```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM account;
```

Outputs:

| ACC_ID | ACCTY_ID | DATE_TIME | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-06-14 12:48:16 | -170 |

and:

```
SELECT * FROM deposition;
```

Outputs:

| DEP_ID | CUST_ID | ACC_ID | AMOUNT | DATE_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 2023-06-14 12:48:16 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | -20 | 2023-06-14 12:48:16 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 50 | 2023-06-14 12:48:16 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | -300 | 2023-06-14 12:48:16 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/voVBoFWT)